# DB Cursor Failures on Google BigQuery

Tags: authentication, google-bigquery

Need to understand why did the below query failed in GCP BigQuery. What are the possible reasons for failure?

The 3 DB cursors which failed for the script to ingest the data into Mongo:
All 3 were running on the same table, and they get authentication error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Login Required.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "required",
        "location": "Authorization",
        "locationType": "header"
      }
    ],
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
  }
}
```

Comment: you have authentication problem, do you use the credential?

Comment: check the https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in